# Timeseries or Time series?

Tags: word-choice

This might be a simple one, but I'd like to have your opinion/authoritative statements: I write a thesis in a technical modelling context, where a mathematical model operates on a discrete set of **timesteps (or time steps?)**. Paramaters/Variables that are defined over this set are then called **timeseries (or time series?)**.

A [Google](http://www.googlebattle.com/?domain=timeseries&domain2=%22time+series%22&submit=Go!) [battle](http://www.googlebattle.com/?domain=timestep&domain2=%22time+step%22&submit=Go!) yields the one-word expressions as clear victors, but [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=time%20series&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) does only like the two-word expressions. So which one is to be preferred? Or is there even a difference in meaning between both variants?

***Conclusion:*** after a temporary confusion from a third option "time-step", I settled for the two word versions for both words.

Comment: _Timestep_ doesn’t look too bad, though _time step_ looks more natural. _Timeseries_ looks very awkward to me, with _time series_ being **far** more natural. Would these time series be the same as [these ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series)?

Comment: Exactly that kind of time series. It is just usual in my (non-native) environment to write them as one word. So I wanted to be sure that I don't change my wording, if both were acceptable alternatives.

Comment: You shouldn’t use German rules of compounding as a guide to English—it’s much more complicated and arbitrary in English than in German where all compounds are always spelt closed, never open. :-)

Comment: If I'm interpreting the results of the 'Google battle' correctly, the clear winner is the well known English open compound "time series" not the closed form "timeseries". Which is exactly what I'd expect: is this a function of where one's computer is situated?

Comment: Interesting, "timeseries" is the winner for me: [timeseries](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=timeseries&btnG=Search): 6,430,000, "[time series](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22time+series%22&btnG=Search)": 4,760,000.

Comment: Ah, I see you have to use double quotes. In that case, I'd wonder about the database they're using. Try (1) a straight Google search for 'timeseries' (omit quotes) and look at the first umpteen returns (they're almost all the open compound, 'time series'). (2) Do a raw Google comparison, hits for "time series" vs hits for "time series" (include double quotes). This gives a very different picture from the 'Google Battle' one.

Comment: The usual venerable dictionaries pronounce clearly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scientific literature, *timestep* is very common. I am surprised that *timeseries* beats *time series* in a google battle though - I would stick with the latter personally.

Comment: I’m guessing part of the reason could be that there is [a Java class](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) (or actually several Java classes, I think) called _TimeSeries_. Nearly all regular Google hits for `"timeseries"` are about the class, rather than the mathematical term.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a good reason to join the two into a single word :) Except perhaps when you want to use a "timestep" or "timeserie" as a unit.

Comment: I don’t see why using it as a unit would change anything … (And there is no such singular as *serie. The word is _a series_ in the singular, too.)

Answer (score 1):

One of my supervisor's corrections for my thesis was to get a consistent usage of either "time series" or "timeseries", in the MS Word orthographic correction both are fine, in a google search as @ojdo mentioned timeseries wins, but in my references whose used the term, over 50 of them used "time series", and could only find a single one using "timeseries". So my choice was "time series".
As a bonus, I had a similar issue when choosing amongst "auto-regressive", "autoregressive" or "auto regressive", went for "autoregressive" in this case, as was also the most used term in my references.

- References in my thesis are scientific papers, books and other dissertations.

Comment: This is a good observation. If you need an adjective to modify the *series* as opposed to the *time*, then expressions like *autoregressive timeseries* don’t look that bad. I still write *time series* myself, because it looks the way it ought to be pronounced, but it doesn’t surprise me that *timeseries* is gaining ground.